# Interrupting multiple running processes in simpy

Tags: python, simpy

Following [docs](https://simpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topical_guides/process_interaction.html#interrupting-another-process), I have 3 of processes that run simultaneously, and the first to finish interrupts the other processes (here `slow_charge` and `slowest_charge`).

```
class EV:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.drive_proc = env.process(self.drive(env))

    def drive(self, env):
        while True:
            # Drive for 20-40 min
            yield env.timeout(30)

            # Park for 1 hour
            print('Start parking at', env.now)

            fastest_charge = env.process(self.bat_ctrl(env,10))
            slow_charge = env.process(self.bat_ctrl(env,60))
            slowest_charge = env.process(self.bat_ctrl(env,80))

            yield slow_charge | fastest_charge | slowest_charge
            if not slow_charge.triggered and not slowest_charge.triggered:
                # Interrupt process if not already done.
                slow_charge.interrupt('drops slow_charge')
                slowest_charge.interrupt('drops slowest_charge')
            print('Stop slow_process at', env.now)
            print('Stop slowest_process at', env.now)

    def bat_ctrl(self, env, delay):
        print('Proc. ctrl. started at', env.now)
        try:
            yield env.timeout(delay)
            print('Proc. ctrl. done at', env.now)
        except simpy.Interrupt as i:
            # Onoes! Got interrupted before the charging was done.
            print('Proc. ctrl. interrupted at', env.now, 'msg:',
                  i.cause)

env = simpy.Environment()
ev = EV(env)
env.run(until=100)
```

If I have an unknown amount of processes with different delay times, is there a more efficient way to interrupt the other running active processes?

SOLUTION following @Michael 's comment:

```
class EV:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.charging_ends = env.event()
        self.drive_proc = env.process(self.drive(env))

    def drive(self, env):
        while True:
            # Drive for 20-40 min
            yield env.timeout(30)

            # Park for 1 hour
            print('Start parking at', env.now)

            self.bat_ctrl_procs = [env.process(self.bat_ctrl(env, delay)) for delay in [10, 60, 80]]
            self.monitor_proc = env.process(self.monitor(env))
            yield self.monitor_proc

    def bat_ctrl(self, env, delay):
        print('Proc. ctrl. started at', env.now)
        try:
            yield env.timeout(delay)
            print('Proc. ctrl. done at', env.now)
            self.charging_ends.succeed()
            self.charging_ends = self.env.event()
        except simpy.Interrupt as i:
            # Onoes! Got interrupted before the charging was done.
            print('Proc. ctrl. interrupted at', env.now, 'msg:',
                  i.cause)
    
    def monitor(self, env):
        yield self.charging_ends
        # print('Charging done at', env.now)
        for proc in self.bat_ctrl_procs:
            try:
                proc.interrupt(f'dropping {proc}')
            except:
                continue

env = simpy.Environment()
ev = EV(env)
env.run(until=100)
```

Comment: You need a class with two processes. One process is the battery control.  The second monitors a passed in global event.  When the event fires this second process would interrupt the battery control process.  When the first battery control finishes, it would trigger the global event.  The other class instants will see the global event got triggered and interrupt their battery control.  Look at the school bell example

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing this out - if I understood it correctly, in the bell example, the `bell` function is battery control and `pupil` is the global monitor?

Comment: yes?  the pupil is the monitor,  and battery control would trigger the event like bell.  also you have one special case where the battery condoler that triggers the event will be done when its monitor fires.

Comment: @Michael your suggestion works! (I think, see edits), but the `drive` while loop doesnt quite add up

Comment: do you need to add a yield self.monitor_proc at the end of your drive loop?

Comment: apologies I overlooked it - it works! added the solution. cheers